# Draggable images on Canvas and mouse events

Tags: canvas, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, draggable, kineticjs

I have a canvas with multiple images draggable on it.
I want to move to the top an image if i click on it but it doesn't work..
If i manually insert the image outside the for cycle all the mouse event works.

here's the code:

```
for(i=0;i<myImagesPath.length;i++)
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = myImagesPath[i];
        myImages[i] = new Kinetic.Image({
          image: img,
          x: 30+100*i,
          y: stage.getHeight() - 100 - 10,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          draggable: true
        });

        // add cursor styling

        myImages[i].on('mouseover', function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });
        myImages[i].on('mouseleave', function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        });
        myImages[i].on('click', function() {
          myImages[i].moveToTop();
        });

        layer.add(myImages[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
myImages[i].on('click', function() {
  myImages[i].moveToTop();
});
```

To this:

```
myImages[i].on('click', function() {
  this.moveToTop();
  layer.draw();
});
```

You need to `draw()` the layer to render the changes on the canvas. Using `this` ensures that the proper node is selected.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/X7UYN/)